# How to open numeric keypad in website using "Contact Form 7"

Tags: wordpress, numeric, keypad

I want to optimize my forms in WordPress websites (contact form 7) and try to make phone fields open with just **numeric keypad** in phones.
Please note that its a website, not an app.

Is there any way for that?

Comment: is your input type is number?

Comment: [number] form tag

Comment: No, its an input created with another plugin and its not number, so I need to make it act like number.